# Finding small square roots modulo P

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algorithms, integer-lattices

Let $P$ be a sufficiently large prime number. Let $x$ be a positive integer, we can write:

$$
\begin{align*}
x^2 = kP + a
\end{align*}
$$

where $0 \leq a < P$. Suppose furthermore that $\sqrt{P} < x < P^{2/3}$, then this implies that $0 < k < P^{1/3}$.

Assuming that as $x$ runs through its range, $a = x^2 \bmod P$ takes on uniformly distributed values in $[0, P)$ (this isn't rigorous but given the quadratic residues are fairly uniformly distributed mod $P$ this is still a good heuristic), then the probability that there exists at least one $x$ such that $a < P^{1/3}$ is well approximated by

$$
\begin{align*}
1 - \left ( 1 - P^{-2/3} \right )^{P^{2/3}} \to 1 - \frac{1}{e} \approx 0.63
\end{align*}
$$

which is independent of $P$. In practice I've found this to be pretty reliable and I can find such $x$ for most choices of $P$.

---

My question is, given a prime $P$, does there exist an efficient algorithm (say, polynomial in $\log P$) to find at least one $x$, if one exists (which as seen above is likely), such that $0 < k < P^{1/3}$ and $0 < a < P^{1/3}$? Of course we can just try all possible values of either $k$ or $a$, but this becomes prohibitively expensive as $P$ grows.

I have tried to apply Coppersmith's method but it does not seem powerful enough for this problem. Lattices seem a natural fit for problems looking for "small solutions" of this kind, but perhaps the fact that $P$ is prime can be of help (since the above does not use the primality of $P$ in any way). Has this problem been studied?

Comment: I found an algorithm that finds $x$ and $k$ in the bounds you mention, but the bound on $a$ is roughly $P^{1/2}$. Is this still useful for you or not at all? If it is useful then I will write an answer

Comment: @Erik We can get $a \approx P^{1/2}$ by picking $x$ to be slightly above the square root of $P$, so it's not a very deep result, but if you took a very different approach than that it could be worth posting for the insights it might give, even if it doesn't get quite all the way there.

Comment: Oh yes, that is much easier. My plan was to consider the Pell-like equation $x^2-y^2P = a$. If you follow [these steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Solutions) then you find your $x,y$ and $a < P^{1/2}$. I don't think this will help since this method probably can't be improved to find a smaller $a$.

Comment: Yes, I see, using the convergents of $\sqrt{P}$. I agree it is unlikely it can be improved to yield better bounds.